# Magento 2 dropdown on hover menu issue

Tags: magento2, css, menu, drop-downs, megamenu

On hover, Magento 2 gives a dropdown functionality, like `megamenu`, `cart`, and `My account` drop-down.
The issue on the hovering the dropdown or pop up menu appears fine but when I remove my mouse and again point it to the area of dropdown submenu it shows the dropdown again although I didn't hover on the anchor or li tag this time.

ex- When I hover my mouse on the anchor of `what's new` then this submenu opens,

> Black marked line is my house position

[image]

When I remove my mouse away from the anchor tag and submenu area and then point my mouse to click other things in the homepage, but since due to previous `what's new` hover submenu still takes some kind of `z-index` so it again opens the submenu

[image]

This is awkward behavior. It works fine when I click somewhere else after the first hover and then try to hover.

`Mega menu should fade/disappear quickly when user leaves the menu area. If within short time user moves around Add to cart option, menu becomes visible distracting the user`

How to fix this issue